# How to print all the nodes in a circular linked list in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a circular linked list in C, however I cant seem to print the nodes one by one. Below is the code for assigning the values and then printing them. Whenever I run it, all it prints out is "NULL". I would like to know what should i do so that it prints out "1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ...."

```
void tail_insert(struct Node * head, struct Node * tail, int num){
    struct Node * p = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    p->info = num;
    p->next = head;

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = p;
        tail = head ;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = p;
        tail = p;
}
}

void print_list(struct Node * head)
{
  struct Node * current = head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {   
        printf("%d -> ", current->info);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

int main(){
struct Node * head = NULL, * tail = NULL;
int num = 0;
    int length;
    int deletespace;
    scanf("%d %d", &length, &deletespace);

for (int i = 1; i < length+1 ; i++){
    tail_insert(head, tail, i);
}

print_list(head);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting nodes printed is because of how pass by value works. When you call `tail_insert`, you're passing a basic pointer. Dereferencing and modifying this inside the function would modify the values pointed to by `head` and `tail`, but not carry changes to the pointers themselves outside the function.

One way of fixing this is to change the `head` and `tail` parameters to be pointers to pointers (`**`) and passing the addresses of those variables where you call the function in `main`.